# add countdown for each row in html table

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table that contains a date column. I want to implement a countdown for each row in the table against one of the date columns.

Here goes my HTML code:

```
 <table  style="width: 100%" id="bidsTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th >Amount</th>

                        <th >Start Date</th>
                        <th >Bids</th>
                        <th >End Date</th>
                        <th ></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td >Peugeot 406 car fro sale</td>
                            <td >800000.00</td>

                            <td >2017-04-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
                            <td >1</td>
                            <td >2017-05-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
                            <td ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td >House for sale in Kubwa</td>
                            <td >4000000.00</td>

                            <td >2017-04-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
                            <td >0</td>
                            <td >2017-06-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
                            <td ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td >Five hectare farming land for lease</td>
                            <td >3000000.00</td>

                            <td >2017-04-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
                            <td >0</td>
                            <td >2017-07-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
                            <td ></td>
                        </tr>



                </tbody>
            </table>
```

And here goes my javascript code

```
 <script>
var table = document.getElementById("bidsTable");
for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    //iterate through rows
    //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop

    var endDate = row.cells[4];
    countDownDate = new Date(endDate.innerHTML.replace(/-/g, "/")).getTime();
    var countDown = row.cells[5];
    // Update the count down every 1 second

    var x = setInterval(
    function () {
        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


        // Display the result in the element
        countDown.innerHTML = (days + "d " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");

         //If the count down is finished, write some text 
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            countDown.innerHTML = "Bid closed";
        }
    }, 1000);
}
 </script>
```

The timer works but only populates the countdown for the last row for the last row of the table.

[image: Result Screenshot]

I've checked but can't figure out why it's not populating the previous rows.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be better to run one interval that loops through each row and do the calculation once per second. Now you have 4 intervals I think.

Comment: I don't get it.
4 intervals?, i have three rows and there could be more.

Comment: I just think in your for loop you create 4 functions, if it loops 4 times.

Comment: run your for loop inside the interval instead :)

Comment: yes, you are right. I just did that and it worked.

Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had to run the loop inside the `setInterval` function and not the `setInterval` function inside the loop.

```
<script>

var table = document.getElementById("bidsTable");

var x = setInterval(
    function () {

        for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
            //iterate through rows
            //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop

            var endDate = row.cells[4];
            countDownDate = new Date(endDate.innerHTML.replace(/-/g, "/")).getTime();
            var countDown = row.cells[5];
            // Update the count down every 1 second

            // Get todays date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now an the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


            // Display the result in the element
            countDown.innerHTML = (days + "d " + hours + "h "
                + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");

            //If the count down is finished, write some text 
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                countDown.innerHTML = "Bid Closed";
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
 </script>
```